# ExtJS 4 change cell value based on another with Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, listener

I have TreeGrid with multiple columns and I use RowEditing plugin to save data. I want to change value of "Total" dynamically when "Price" changes. I made the following, but it doesnt work. 
when I look at "Total" object, I see thet value is changed, but a cant see this in RowEditing plugin at the time of editing and before update.

```
{
    text: 'price',        
    dataIndex: 'price',
    editor: {
    xtype: 'textfield',
            listeners: {
                change: function (field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
                    var selectedModel = MyTree.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                    selectedModel.set('total', 'Total sum is' + field.value);
                }
            }
    }
}, 
{ 
    text: 'total',        
    dataIndex: 'total',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'textfield'
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work too :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

```
var total = MyTree.getPlugin('roweditor').editor.down('textfield[name=total]');
total.setValue('Total sum is' + field.value);`
```